# Gunicorn maximum threads for 1 worker

Tags: multithreading, gunicorn

In terms if Gunicorn workers and threads I need to know if there is a maximum threads that can be assigned to a single worker? I've a flask application for the UI part of a trading bot. What it does it allows the user to create new instances of a trading bot and when a new instance is created, it is added as a new thread. There is a bot manager that allows to stop and start bot instances as threads and also keep track of running threads.

App is dockerized. Gunicorn runs on a single worker (since workers don't share memory between them, or is there a way for the bot manager to speak with other workers?). How many threads can I start on a single worker? Should I specify number of threads for gunicorn?

Currently gunicorn is fired up with following command:

```
gunicorn app:application --worker-tmp-dir /dev/shm --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --timeout 600 --workers 1
```

Can I start lets say 8 threads on a single worker? What benefits will it reap?

```
gunicorn app:application --worker-tmp-dir /dev/shm --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --timeout 600 --workers=1 --threads=8
```